# Keras, What's the difference between keras.backend.concatenate and Keras.layers.Concatenate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am starting to use the Keras. However, I am confused about the difference between `Keras.layers.Concatenate` and `keras.backend.concatenate`. It seems different.

For example, when I use the `Keras.layers.Concatenate`, there is no error. But, when I use the `keras.backend.concatenate`, it will report the error:

```
RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("concat_1:0", shape=(?, 227, 227, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_2_art"
```

The code as followed:

```
input_nc_tensor = Input(shape=(227, 227, 1), name='NC_input')
input_nc_tensor_3channel = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_nc_tensor, input_nc_tensor, input_nc_tensor])
input_nc_tensor_3channel = keras.backend.concatenate([input_nc_tensor, input_nc_tensor, input_nc_tensor], axis=-1)

input_art_tensor = Input(shape=(227, 227, 1), name='ART_input')
input_art_tensor_3channel = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_art_tensor, input_art_tensor, input_art_tensor])
input_art_tensor_3channel = keras.backend.concatenate([input_art_tensor, input_art_tensor, input_art_tensor], axis=-1)

input_pv_tensor = Input(shape=(227, 227, 1), name='PV_input')
input_pv_tensor_3channel = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_pv_tensor, input_pv_tensor, input_pv_tensor])
input_pv_tensor_3channel = keras.backend.concatenate([input_pv_tensor, input_pv_tensor, input_pv_tensor], axis=-1)
```

Comment: Yes, there is a same question. Thank you！